# Using Docker Image for Python automation run

Tags: docker

I am using the Python framework for automation. The framework uses python 3.9 and some automation specific libraries which are mentioned in requirements.txt. The framework is common across teams, so the docker image will be created only with python 3.9 and requirement.txt and the test we are interested to run will be pulled from the bit bucket. Is it mandatory always the test code also should be added to the image? Please advice

Comment: "Is it mandatory always the test code also should be added to the image?" -- only if you want to run the tests.

Comment: The setup you describe doesn't sound like it needs Docker at all; end users can pretty straightforwardly create a Python virtual environment and install the exact package and versions listed in the `requirements.txt` file, with a total of 3 fairly standard commands.

Comment: we want to run using Jenkins pipeline, the Jenkins local instance can refer venv, for remote we are using docker image and we make it common across teams

Comment: @DavidMaze please help.